# How can I get Spring Tools Suite recognize the spring annotations

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite, spring-annotations

I pulled a repository from GitHub, and opened the project in Spring Tools Suite. It is a spring boot project with many annotations, but STS is not recognizing any of them. The errors are all like "Autowired cannot be resolved to a type".

[image]

I used STS before, and all the projects I created on my own can function normally, the annotations can be recognized.

[image]

I searched for some answers on Stack Overflow, they say that I need to include maven in my build path, I tried, but still it prevents me with an error.

[image]

How can I get STS to function normally and make it recognize the annotations?

Comment: How did you add the project into sts... try adding it as a existing maven project and see

Comment: @SriVenkataPavanKumarMHS I used to "open projects from file system", I just tried again by import -> maven -> existing maven projects -> browse -> selected my project, but the "finish" button is greyed out, I cannot get it imported.

Comment: I did not look at the images before... so the project you are trying to import is a gradle project not a maven... so you need to import it as a gradle but still there are few more commands you have to run so that the class path gets all the jars..

Comment: @SriVenkataPavanKumarMHS Thanks so much, I just imported as gradle project and everything works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import it as a gradle project and see the magic happen by itself... :)